# How to let menuItems stay visible after a menu is clicked in javaFX?

Tags: javafx, menu, menuitem, menubar, visible

this is my problem: I'm developing a javaFX application and I have a MenuBar with 2 Menus.
Each Menu has its own MenuItems to show but these are only showed for a moment, exactly when I click on the Menu they belong.
This way, I cannot click on the MenuItems because they disapper too quickly.

How can I make these MenuItems to stay visible not only when I click on a Menu, but as long as I don't click somewhere else in my window?

Thx in advance

Comment: Try mouse over the menu Item?

Comment: MenuItems disappear too quickly as soon as I release the mouseclick on the name of the Menu

Answer (score 0):

Try CustomMenuItem and set setHideOnClick to false:

```
public class JavaFXApplication84 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("Open");
        CustomMenuItem customMenuItem = new CustomMenuItem(new Label("Close"));
        customMenuItem.setHideOnClick(false);
        customMenuItem.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("You clicked me!"));

        Menu menu1 = new Menu("File");
        menu1.getItems().addAll(menuItem1,  customMenuItem);

        Menu menu2 = new Menu("Options");
        Menu menu3 = new Menu("Help");

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menu1, menu2, menu3);            

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(menuBar);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: You might have some other problem. Post minimal and complete code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: You might have a stuck key or something.

Comment: I deleted the part of the FXML file in which I declared the menuBar, menu and MenuItems, I created these nodes programmatically and it works!